# Create a transparent shadow in iframes using CSS

Tags: css

I'm struggling with CSS design on my [website](https://shir0206.github.io/NyquistOptics-Web/).

I'm trying to design the navigation bar above in shape of bottom-corners-rounded and add a black shadow below.

See example I created in Photoshop:
[image: See example I created in Photoshop]

Since I'm using iframes, and I try to avoid changeing the heights, it's pretty complicated for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.title {
    color: #17375e;
    text-align: center;
}

.tabContainer .buttonContainer {
    height: 15%;
}

.tabContainer .buttonContainer button {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #aac0e8;
}

.tabContainer .tabPanel {
    border-top: 0.5em solid #dce6f2;
    height: 85%;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: none;
}

#parameters {
    padding: 10px;
}

.fov {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.natoTarget {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.humanTarget {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.objectTarget {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.settings .parameters {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.settings .linePairs {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.settings .targetSize {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.infoContainer {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    text-align: center;
    background: #dce6f2;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.infoTitle {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2);
    margin: 0%;
}

.parameterContainer .fullBlurContainer,
.parameterContainer .halfBlurContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 29.4px;
    height: 29.4px;
    filter: blur(100);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parameterContainer .fullBlurContainer img {
    border: 1px solid #aac0e8;
    filter: blur(2px);
}

.parameterContainer .halfBlurContainer img {
    border: 1px solid #aac0e8;
    filter: blur(1px);
}

input[type=number] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    background: transparent;
    width: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}


/* label underline focus color */

input[type=number]:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #aac0e8;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5px 0 0 #aac0e8;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    /* Firefox */
}

.parameterContainer {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    text-align: left;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.calc {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    background-image: url(img/calculator.svg), radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 60%, 100%;
    background-position: center, center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.save {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    background-image: url(img/save.svg), radial-gradient(#aac0e8, #b9cde5, #dce6f2);
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-size: 50%, 100%;
    background-position: center, center;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.my-float {
    margin-top: 22px;
}

output {
    margin: 3em 0% 3em 0%;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background: #ffffff
}

#parameters,
#linePairs,
#targetSize {
    background: #aac0e8;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#icon {
    border: none;
    align-self: auto;
    background-image: url(img/icon.png);
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#iconContainer {
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url(img/icon.png);
}

.indexContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabContainer {
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#ref_calculateHFOV,
#ref_calculateFocalLength,
#ref_settings {
    height: 15%;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #aac0e8;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: bold;
    /**/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>DRI Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="calculateFOV.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="indexContainer">
        <div class="tabNav">
            <a href="calculateHFOV.html" id="ref_calculateHFOV" target="tab">HFOV Calculator</a>
            <a href="calculateFocalLength.html" id="ref_calculateFocalLength" target="tab">Focal Length Calculator</a>
            <a href="settings.html" id="ref_settings" target="tab">Settings</a>
        </div>

        <iframe src="calculateHFOV.html" class="tabContainer" name="tab">
            <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i might be blind but i cannot see the difference between the 2 pictures. Can you be more specific ? And replicate your current result in a stack overflow code snippet

Comment: @MihaiT I try to change the shape of the navigation bar (edit to a rectangle with bottom-corners-rounded) and add a black shadow below the rectangle .

Comment: well use the same styles on the navigation bar as you used on the other elements that have bottom rounded corners and shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below an example of shadow and rounded corners. You can change the values of the `border-radius` and of the `shadow` blur and vertical length as you please.

Some advice:

Do not use `camelCase` when naming html attributes. Use `kebab-case` instead. `indexContainer` turns into `index-container`.

Also do not use `float` never ever for layout purposes. Especially when i see that you know about flex.

Let me know if this solves your problem.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


.index-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
 
}
.tab-nav {
  display:flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 9px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  overflow:hidden;
  }


body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#ref_calculateHFOV,
#ref_calculateFocalLength,
#ref_settings {
  height: 15%;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #aac0e8;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: bold;
  /**/
}
```

```html
<div class="index-container">
  <div class="tab-nav">
    <a href="calculateHFOV.html" id="ref_calculateHFOV" target="tab">HFOV Calculator</a>
    <a href="calculateFocalLength.html" id="ref_calculateFocalLength" target="tab">Focal Length Calculator</a>
    <a href="settings.html" id="ref_settings" target="tab">Settings</a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code-review!
About my problem - if I try using your solution - when I click any link in the nav, the shadow is gone under the new page that is opening.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? the page appears as an iframe ? so it's not a new page but loaded in the iframe below ? add a `margin-bottom:50px`  ( or how much you need ) to `.index-container`

Comment: margin wouldn't help, because it would add a white background under the shadow, and not transparent. see example - https://ibb.co/WVnpLp8